# SQL View - join keyword in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

If I have a SQL view which generates an example query like

```
Select [A], [B], [C (Join)] from X
```

then what does (Join) signify and how can I get details about this. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Is all that text returned from the view? What do you expect?

Comment: In the present form you have 3 columns: one called `A`, one Called `B`, and one called `c (Join)` all coming from a table `X`  so the c (join) is nothing more than a column name, albeit a strange one.

Comment: Object names use Brackets (`[]`) as quote operators in T-SQL. If that is literally your SQL, then the name of your 3rd column is `C (Join)`. The `(Join)` is part of the name, it doesn't signify anything.

Comment: Wow, if that's it, that might be the worst column name ever.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, identifiers can consist of letters, numbers, and underscore (and maybe another character or two).  If they contain anything else, then the identifier needs to be escaped.

What your query means is that table `X` has a column called `C (Join)`.  It is that simple.  That is a bad choice of column name, because it needs to be escaped.

I would much prefer:

```
select A, B, C_Join
from X ;
```